# Android SDK emulator is really bugged with platform 3.0

Tags: android

Is there a way to make the emulator work correctly ? it is extremly slow and there is really no way to debug application this way.

Anyone experiencing this ?

Note : This is for the android 3.x platform of the SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is experiencing this issue, even who have Intel i7 with 16 gb of ram...

The problem is that the biggest resolution (mostly 1280x800) have killed the emulator performance...

At the last google I/O some kind of hardware acceleration was shown, but it's in early stage of development I think.. But the performance were way better.

Today the only solution to develop on Honeycomb is to buy a real tablet..

Comment: I see. This is rather sad ATM. Hopefully this gonna be fixed before september.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Emulator is slow with every OS version (but Google is working on it). Also, if you're running the Emulator on an already slow system, this slows it down, too.

If you're getting any errors, feel free to post the outputted error-messages. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to wait until the performance-issues are solved.